# Heroku Rake Process Exits Early, Doesn't Fully Run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a rake task for use with Heroku Scheduler. My issue is, when I run the rake task on Heroku, the process never fully completes, instead it exits early.

What I am trying to do is perform an action on every member of an array. This array has 4,500 items. The function is like this on my `Action` model:

```
def my_rake_task(some_array)
    i = 0
    while i < some_array.count do
        puts "#{i} number in {some_array[i]}"
        i += 1
    end
end
```

and is set up in `scheduler.rake` like:

```
desc "Run my rake task"
task :my_rake_task => :environment do
    Action.my_rake_task
end
```

When I run this locally, everything is fine, and I'll see all 4,500 items in the array properly output. When I push to Heroku and check it via `Heroku run rake my_rake_task` it will output anywhere from ~1,000 to ~1,600 of the lines, and then stop.

My logs look like:

```
2015-01-17T16:44:28.259815+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake my_rake_task` by my_user_name
2015-01-17T16:44:31.729533+00:00 heroku[run.8495]: Awaiting client
2015-01-17T16:44:31.765515+00:00 heroku[run.8495]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake my_rake_task`
2015-01-17T16:44:32.155205+00:00 heroku[run.8495]: State changed from starting to up
2015-01-17T16:45:31.914275+00:00 heroku[run.8495]: State changed from up to complete
2015-01-17T16:45:31.896364+00:00 heroku[run.8495]: Process exited with status 0
```

I'm wondering if this could be because I'm only using one dyno? Or if there's some other reason? Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based off the limited information that your provided I have a few solutions for you that can ensure your tasks run as intended.

First when you run rake tasks on Heroku, especially if they are long running tasks, run them detached.  This will ensure that the connection to your terminal does not interfere with the task.  For instance if you close your terminal before the task is complete it will end it prematurely.

```
heroku run:detached rake my_rake_task
```

Secondly if you are checking your logs and only see ~1600 lines of output, ensure that you are requesting more of the logs:

```
heroku logs -n 5000
```

Third you should be using a delayed_job https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job
that will put everything in a queue, run tasks on worker dynos, have error reporting, and full logs for each task/job.  You can view a rails cast on delayed job here http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job

Comment: thanks @heading_to_tahiti . I've used Delayed Jobs before, but am trying to avoid using it on this project since it requires an extra dyno. I tried `heroku run:detached rake my_rake_task`, and the items I'm seeing now are 1) out of order, which is odd, and 2) only those items of the array greater than about 2,800. So still not working quite right. My main question then, is this an issue with how Heroku manages dynos, and does it mean that an app with only one dyno is severely limited in its functionality? Kind of frustrating since this one rake task is literally the only thing this app does.

Comment: well no... but I found the issue. In my process I was calling a API that consistently failed due to the volume of requests. Locally I had this call commented out, hence locally everything worked, but in production it would run, API failed, process got halted, and as the task then exited the rest of the command was never called.